# How can I re-scale a forest plot in RStudio?

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I am trying to reproduce the plot from the example dataset in the robumeta package in R Studio. While the script works (as expected), I can only see a fraction of the graph. When I increase the size of the window, I get to see more but never the whole thing because apparently, my computer screen is too small and there is no option to scroll up or down. Is there a way to re-scale the forest plot or to print it to pdf (with several pages, if needed)?

Here's the code from package description file:

```
install.packages("robumeta")
library(robumeta)
data(oswald2013.ex1)
oswald_intercept <- robu(formula = effect.size ~ 1, data =         oswald2013.ex1, studynum = Study, var.eff.size = var.eff.size, rho = 0.8, small = TRUE)
forest.robu(oswald_intercept, es.lab = "Crit.Cat", study.lab = "Study",
            "Effect Size" = effect.size, # optional column
            "Weight" = r.weights) # optional column
```

Answer (score 0):

```
png(filename, height, width, pointsize)
#your plot code
dev.off()
```

in which you play around with the height, width, and pointsize parameters should allow you to save the graph to your desired view size. It won't save as a pdf, but rather a png, which should be ok if your goal is just to view the entire forest plot.